# Duplicate key handling in collections

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, collections

I have a microsoft visual basic collection (in the namespace `Microsoft.VisualBasic`) - which uses the Microsoft.VisualBasic.Dll library.

```
private Collection myCollection;
```

When i add values to it, I get the following error:

> Add failed, duplicate key cannot be inserted

How do i handle that?  I need to pass all the ID's.  For example, if have a collection of ID's (e.g. 10, 11, 12, 13, 10), if the code 10 repeats, this line fails:

```
myCollection.Add(myIDs.ID);  // this code throws exception
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.collection.aspx

Before you add, check to see if the collection already contains the key.

```
if(!myCollection.Contains(myIDs.ID))
    myCollection.Add(myIDs.ID);
```

Comment: In addition to TyCobb's answer, you might want to consider the note in the remarks section of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.collection.aspx : "Whenever possible, you should use the generic collections in the System.Collections.Generic namespace or the System.Collections.Concurrent namespace instead of a Visual Basic Collection."

Answer (score 2):

If you want the duplicates which is what I think you mean by "I need to pass all the ID's" you may want to use a List or even better a List(of Integer) instead of the Collection.

```
List<int>  IntList = new List<int>;
           IntList.Add(MyIds.ID);
```